# Incorrect button position in window when padding added to body

Tags: java, css, maven, gwt, gxt

I am trying to run 'Simple dialog' example on my side. I have created a project from public archetype by following instructions from here http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3.x/getting_started/maven/Archetypes.html

Then I have copied and pasted example code from https://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:dialog that creates a 'simple' dialog. Now my SandboxyEntryPoint class looks like:

```
package com.sencha.examples.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.sencha.gxt.core.client.GXT;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.Dialog;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.box.MessageBox;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.button.TextButton;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.event.SelectEvent;
import com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.event.SelectEvent.SelectHandler;

/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class SandboxyEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {

  final String TEXT = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing" +
          " and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's" +
          " standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.";

  @Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
    String version = GXT.getVersion().getRelease();
    TextButton textButton = new TextButton("Verify GXT Works: Version=" + version);
    RootPanel.get().add(textButton);
    textButton.addSelectHandler(new SelectHandler() {
      @Override
public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        final Dialog simple = new Dialog();
        simple.setHeadingText("Dialog Test");
        simple.setPredefinedButtons(Dialog.PredefinedButton.YES, Dialog.PredefinedButton.NO);
        simple.setBodyStyleName("pad-text");
        simple.add(new Label(TEXT));
        simple.getBody().addClassName("pad-text");
        simple.setHideOnButtonClick(true);
        simple.setWidth(300);
        simple.show();
//        MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox("GXT Works.");
//        messageBox.show();
}
    });
  }

}
```

Then I went to the 'Sandboxy.css' and added the following css-class:

```
.pad-text {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

The main issue that I experience here is that control buttons at the bottom are placed incorrectly with a gap at the right:

[image: Incorrect layout]

While in examples everything seems to be correct:

[image: Correct layout in examples]

I have tried both GWT 2.6.1 and 2.7.0 with same result. Please point me what am I doing wrong?

*P.S. I have already asked this question [on Sencha forum](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?304886-Incorrect-button-position-in-window-when-padding-added-to-body&p=1114257) but looks like it's dead. So I am asking here.*